# How to make fixed aspect ratio of an UWP page

Tags: uwp

I make an UWP page, and I hope to fix its aspect ratio (value of width/length) when user changes the page size. I used below codes, but the aspect ratio is still not fixed.

```
    public List1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.SizeChanged -= List1_SizeChanged;
        this.SizeChanged += List1_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void List1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Height = this.ActualWidth * 1080/1920;
        this.MaxHeight = this.Height;
        this.MinHeight = this.Height;
    }
```

How to do it then?

Answer (score 0):

It works via function binding:

XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="aspectresize.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    Width="500" 
    Height="{x:Bind GetAspectHeight(Width), Mode=OneWay}"
    Background="Lime"/>
```

Code behind

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace aspectresize
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
            => InitializeComponent();

        private double GetAspectHeight(double width)
            => width * (1080d / 1920);
    }
}
```

While running try to change page `Width` in XAML. It should change height respectively.